# Using ROS Melodic with Python 3

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS M following the [installation instructions,](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu). I installed the desktop configuration, but when tried step 1.6, `rosdep` installation, it doesn't work for `python3-rosdep`. Is this the right way of doing it?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ sudo apt install python3-rosdep
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-rosdep : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rosdistro but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rospkg but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rosdep-modules (>= 0.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**EDIT**:

If I try to install `python3-rospkg` it will attempt to remove a lot of `ros-*` packages I just installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348093/using-ros-melodic-with-python-3/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2020-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The binary packages provided by the buildfarm target Python 2 for ROS Melodic. Melodic does not support Python 3 out-of-the-box. See [REP-3: Target platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023).

The first ROS 1 release with official support for Python 3 will be ROS Noetic Ninjemys ([ros-infrastructure/rep#202](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/202)). See also [wiki/UsingPython3](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3) and [wiki/noetic/Migration](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Migration).

If you need Python 3 with Melodic, you'll have to build it from source. See #q237613 for a Q&A with some example workflows.

Note: building (base) ROS from source means you cannot use `apt` any more to install additional packages (as those will only work with Python 2).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2020-04-01**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for your explanation. It is clear now.